# Dash not displaying properly

Tags: unity, 11.10, unity-dash

I can only get unity to display properly at a lower (ugly-looking) resolution. Is there a way to fix this. I cannot go full screen. I can not find any bug reports that have similar problems.

I have blacklisted intel_ips because it had failed to i915 symbols.

This is common problem in linux and the solution on many websites and bug reports (which has worked up until now) is to blacklist intel_ips.

I am using a gateway laptop. 64 bit oneiric ocelot fully updated. installed from the daily build yesterday. this problem is not present when intel_ips is not blacklist and I resume normal boot from grub2 menu. but i cannot get a higher resolution than 1440x900 and the native resolution 1600x900.

I cannot post images because of the spam mechanism thing but basically there is a second dash menu that tries to show and they interlap and there is no fullscreen corner button at the bottom.

```
lshw -C video
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 18
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:41 memory:f0000000-f03fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:1800(size=8)
```

Comment: This ppa does not support oneiric but I do have the version installed that is available in the ppa already.

Comment: You should have enough rep now to post a picture, if not, just leave it as a comment and I'll edit it in for ya.

Comment: @user26707, does the answer by Bruno work? If it does, can you please accept the answer to "close" the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the latest drivers for your video card:

1) Add the repo:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:glasen/intel-driver
```

2) update sources and packages

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

3) install the xserver-xorg-video-intel drivers

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```